# Ubuntu Oneko mouse pointer animation distorted

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, animations

***I know this is one of the less important questions here . But Cats!!.***

I am using oneko and it works fine when the cat is chasing the mouse pointer but when the cat stops in the mouse pointer the cat animation gets garbled and distorted

when the cat is running

[image]

when the cat stops on the pointer the animation gets distorted
[image]

**what is wrong with my cat and how to fix my cat ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 17.04 with Oneko.
I think the problem is the shape or the shadow of the animation.
In the terminal I ran the following command and it solved the problem:

```
oneko -noshape
```

More info [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man6/oneko.6.html).

Comment: You are my new favourite person in stack exchange man .. god bless you

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem because now oneko has a non-transparent box around him.